# Return an Either object from a different Either in Dartz

Tags: dart, functional-programming, dartz

I have a function in Dart where I would like to return an Either value to propagate a Failure(left) or an Object(right). These data are dependent on a different Either value in a function likes this in Dart, but currently it is returning null, even though the input Either is returning a (right) value.

```
Future<Either<Failure, User>> getUser(String uid) async {
    Either<Failure, DocumentSnapshot> document;
    document = await _database.getDocumentById(uid);
    // _database.getDocument function returns a Either<Failure, Document> object

   //  But when I fold the value to propagate the failure or return an User, I get null as 
   //return
   document.fold((failure) => Left(failure), (document) => Right(User.fromJson(document.data))); 

  }
```

The User.fromJson function was tested and is working well, but I cannot return the Either object

Comment: The fold either evaluates to `Left<A>` or `Right<B>`. Either way it cannot be `null`. The problem is probably caused by the `Future` or `async`/`await`.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but you could simplify the last line to `document.map((document) => User.fromJson(document.data))`

Answer (score 0):

Dart implicitly returns `null` if the function does not have a return statement.

https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#missing_return

So simply adding a return statement should solve your issue.